# Access the queried data from Vue component using Gridsome

Tags: vue.js, graphql, static-pages, gridsome

I am new to Gridsome as well as to GraphQL. However I'm not using the GraphQL for this project.
I just have a Gridsome project setup and some JSON data and I'm trying to define it globally so that I can access it from all my Vue pages and Components. (I know it can be imported into the component but I'm looking for more "Gridsome way" of doing that).
I've done following steps to achieve this:

1) Created a folder for the Json file: `data/myJson.json`.
   Json-file:

```
{
    "startPage": {
        "title": "Welcher Typ bist Du?",
        "subtitle": "Los geht's beim lustigen Datev-Quiz!",
        "startButton": "Quiz starten"
    }
}
```

2) My `gridsome.server.js` is looking like this:

```
var myJson = require('./data/questions.json');
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.loadSource(store => {
    const startPage = store.addContentType({
      typeName: 'StartPage'
    });

    startPage.addNode({
      title: 'StartPageInfo',
      fields: {
        title: myJson.startPage.title,
        subtitle: myJson.startPage.subtitle,
        startButton: myJson.startPage.startButton
      }
    })
  })
}
```

3) And I'm querying this data in the `index.vue` page.

I can acces this data in my template. So if I do something like this

```
<h4 v-html="$page.allStartPage.edges[0].node.fields"></h4>
```

then it works perfectly fine.

My problem is however, that I can't acces this queried data within Vue's `data` object or within methods and so on.
So something like this:

```
data() {
  retrun {
    START_PAGE_END_POINT: this.$page.allStartPage.edges[0].node.fields
  }
}
```

gives me an error message and tells that the `$page` is not defined.

Any minds what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've figured it out.
I was able to access `this.$page` variable in the `created()` lifecycle hook of vue and not in the `data` object itself.

The code is looking like this.
I first define the variables with initial value of `null` in the `data` object:

```
data() {
      return {
        START_PAGE_END_POINT: null,

        title: null,
        subtitle: null,
        startButton: null
      }
    }
```

Then in the `created()` lifecycle hook I'm assigning the right values to theese variables:

```
created() {
      if (this.$page) {
        this.START_PAGE_END_POINT = this.$page.allStartPage.edges[0].node.fields;

        this.title = this.START_PAGE_END_POINT.title,
        this.subtitle = this.START_PAGE_END_POINT.subtitle,
        this.startButton = this.START_PAGE_END_POINT.startButton
      }
    }
```

I'm still curious why is it not possible to access the `$page` variable in the `data` object itself.

Comment: if you `console.log(this)` in your component, you will see that the data object is transformed into `this._data` and that `$page` is at the same level `this.$page`. The `$` indicates that it is some kind of module such as `this.$router` or `this.$store`

Comment: I found you can access `this.$page` and `this.$static` in the `mounted()` hook, too, which helps if you want to save data from the query straight into a `data()` variable.